# 0x800a03ec {SaveAs method of Workbook class failed} error in TCOM/TCL

Tags: excel, com, tcl

I'm trying to write some data from TCL to a CSV file, but i get the   0x800a03ec {SaveAs method of Workbook class failed} when executing it. Any idea why this is happening?

```
set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]
$application Visible 1

set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
set workbook [$workbooks Add]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
#set worksheet [$worksheets Item "Sheet1"]
set cells [$worksheet Cells]

set rows [array size atten]
for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
    $cells Item $row "B" $atten($row)
}

$workbook SaveAs Filename {c:\tst.csv}
$application Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your SaveAs line. It should read

```
$workbook SaveAs {c:\tst.csv}
```

Also you may want to change the location from C:\ as that is often not a writable location,.

Comment: i tried saving to different folder, also changed <= to < but still I'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you change the SaveAs line as I said? I was able to reproduce your error and changing that line fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [plain googling for this](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x800a03ec%20excel) yields lots of possible causes and solutions (from manual setting the output format to hitting the row limit to hitting the string length limit etc).  Most definitely, this exception has nothing to do with Tcl (since it's just what COM marshals from an Excel instance), so just read through the discussions linked from the search output and see what applies to your case.

Comment: I'm able to write the data in CSV format. But the data is all corrupted. For example, when i opened it with notepad the data is corrupted, I mean i don't see the data seperated by comma. Is there any problem with the method that i use to write the data to CSV format??

Comment: Yes, @amateur: Excel does not infer the file format from its extension; instead, you have to use two-argument call to `SaveAs`, passing the desired [format code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff198017.aspx) as its second argument (6 in your case), see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e33e36.aspx) for how to call `SaveAs` properly.

Comment: I have to add that if you're using Excel solely to generate a CSV file, this is a *very* bad idea compared to using the `csv` package from Tcllib--both performance-wise and portability-wise (I mean, across different Windows machines) and maintenance-wise. I recommend you to better spend your time learning how to use more sensible tools for the job (`csv` and `struct::matrix` packages).