# Data corrupted while storing file in CSV format with excel via TCOM

Tags: excel, tcl

```
set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]
$application Visible 1
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
set workbook [$workbooks Add]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
set cells [$worksheet Cells]
set rows [array size atten]
for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
    $cells Item $row "B" $atten($row)
}
$workbook SaveAs Filename {c:\tst.csv}
$application Quit
```

Hi.I'm able to write the data in CSV format. But the data is all corrupted. For example, when i opened it with notepad the data is corrupted, I mean i don't see the data seperated by comma. Is there any problem with the method that i use to write the data to CSV format??

Comment: I answered this in my second comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9610107/720999) to your previous question, @amateur.  May be it's time to start actually thinking, reading and googling before posting anothert question for each tiny problem occuring with the same simple program? It starts looking like we doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the file name end in `.csv` isn't enough to tell Excel to save as CSV. You have to pass a file type constant to the `SaveAs` method. Not sure about Tcl syntax, but I'm guessing the correct invocation of `SaveAs` would be

```
$workbook SaveAs Filename {c:\tst.csv} FileFormat xlCSV
```

[SaveAs documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: If not `xlCSV`, `[expr 6]` (the value from the enumeration).